# spa/meson.build:29:4: ERROR: Dependency "bluez" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake while installing PIPEWIRE in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: error-handling, ubuntu-16.04, bluez, ninja, meson-build

I am trying to install Pipewire in my Ubuntu 16.04 x86 amd64 machine using instructions found here : https://pipewire.org/#getting

> ./autogen.sh --prefix=$PREFIX

On running the above command, I get this error

```
spa/meson.build:29:4: ERROR: Dependency "bluez" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

I have installed bluez already. This is the output for running

```
**sudo apt-get install bluez**
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     bluez is already the newest version (5.37-0ubuntu5.3).
     0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

The files that are required to do development on top of a package are often separate (since this is really only needed by developers, and would take up too much size for no reason otherwise).

In your case, the package you're looking for is [`libbluetooth-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libbluetooth-dev). So you can do `sudo apt install libbluetooth-dev`

Comment: After installing bluetooth, It now says jack is not found

Comment: Same spiel: `sudo apt install libjack-dev`

Comment: Please also mark the question as answered if it solved your original problem